# Testing the analyticity of $2\ln z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> Test whether the function $2\ln z$ is analytic.

I have tried to test this function for analyticity by letting $z=x+iy$, but I have failed to separate the real and imaginary parts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you define $\log z$ ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:)** The logarithm is a multi-valued function and the main branch of logarithm, that is
$$\log z=\ln r+i\theta\hspace{2cm}r>0,~0\leq\theta<2\pi$$
is analytic in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, to verify we can let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and whether it satisfies the relation
$$e^{-i\theta}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\dfrac{1}{iz}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$$